# Запятая при "прежде чем"

Tags: пунктуация

В предложении типа "нужно сделать это прежде чем другое случится"

Вторая часть - точно второе предложение в составе сложного. Только где нужно ставить запятую: перед "прежде" или перед "чем" (что-то меня тянет в сторону второго варианта)

Answer (score 2):

Тут может быть двоякая пунктуация. Если сделать акцент на слове *прежде*, то запятую можно поставить между "прежде" и "чем". Во всех остальных случаях логично ставить после "это", не разделяя составной союз. Впрочем, у автора могут быть и другие резоны для выбора места для запятой. Главное, что оба варианта формально допустимы.

//-------

ПРЕЖДЕ(,) ЧЕМ, союз

Синтаксические конструкции, начинающиеся с союза «прежде чем», выделяются знаками препинания (запятыми). При этом первый знак препинания чаще ставится перед составным союзом, а не между его частями (перед словом «чем»). О факторах, влияющих на расстановку знаков препинания, см. в Приложении 3.

Нередко случается на войне, что командир, четыре атаки которого не принесли успеха, чувствует надобность подумать, прежде чем отдать команду на пятую. В. Быков, Волчья стая. Предупреждаю тебя: когда будешь ему представляться, – войди тихо; не начинай говорить, прежде чем тебя не спросят; спросят – отвечай, понижая голос насколько возможно… Д. Григорович, Карьерист. «Когда найдено было электричество, – быстро перебил Левин, – то было только открыто явление, и неизвестно было, откуда оно происходит и что оно производит, и века прошли прежде, чем подумали о приложении его». Л. Толстой, Анна Каренина. Воротник поблагодарил и радостно согласился прежде, чем Олечка успела сообразить, в чем дело. Н. Тэффи, Жизнь и воротник.
//-------

http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_628

Answer (score 2):

Я бы поставила так:Нужно сделать это прежде, чем другое случится.-акцент на том, что нужно опередить. Но если автор сделает акцент на том, что это следует обязательно сделать - будет так:Нужно сделать это, прежде чем другое случится. Если б стояло в начале предложения, запятой не было бы однозначно:Прежде чем другое случится,нужно сделать это.-акцент на слове ЭТО.